# Bluetooth service being skipped

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero, systemd

I'm attempting to use a HC-06 bluetooth module on a raspberry pi zero (not w). I have it wired correctly and have used it before on older versions of raspbian, but I decided to update to the lastest raspbian buster (July 2019) and now I can't seem to get the bluetooth module working.

When I type the command `systemctl status bluetooth` I get the following output:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jul 10 03:03:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

I have enabled the serial-interface through `raspi-config`, but it appears that some setting is causing it to not look for a bluetooth module at all. Has anybody seen this before? I can seem to find this same issue with this error message.

Consequently with the bluetooth service not working, `bluetoothctl` seems to freeze and not allow any input.

Comment: But HC06 does not link to Rpi using Bluetooth.  HC06 talks to Rpi using UART.  HC06 is a "serial through thing", which serially passing Rpi's serial data to the other side's Bluetooh guy, say android phone.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

How can Rpi talk to HC06?

***Answer***

1. Let us use the HC06 Module, Reference (1) as an example.
2. Let us first study the HC06 chip specification and user guide, Reference (2).
3. The chip uses two UART pins, TxD and RxD to talk to the Rpi, using AT commands.
4. Now let us look at the block diagram.

[image: hc06 block diagram_2019sep1601]

5. Let us first make sure that the HC06 module is working, by

> Sending the AT command "***AT***".
>
> If the module returns "***OK***",
>
> then everything is fine.

*The user guide describes the AT command set in Chapter 9.*

[image: AT command]

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

(1) [AliExpress Bluetooth HC-06 Module US$3](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32857133517.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.f5836f3bRgpitt&algo_pvid=1aec1793-99ff-4b1c-a995-6f05f7d8c1d9&algo_expid=1aec1793-99ff-4b1c-a995-6f05f7d8c1d9-4&btsid=acd9d924-32ae-42e7-9ae4-dfa824b7bfb4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_9,searchweb201603_52)

(2) [HC06 User Manual - Guangzhou HC Info Tech](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Components/RF/BLUETOOTH-SERIAL-HC-06/resources/hc06.pdf)

(3) [HC05/06 Modules and AT Commands](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98541/how-to-send-data-from-raspberry-pi-to-avr-over-bluetooth)

(4) [BlueZ V5.5 Problems](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99017/connection-failed-between-raspberry-pi-zero-w-and-android-via-bluetooth-le)